# Font Awesome 4.2

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I have already been using font-awesome 3.2.1 in my project. Now I wish to upgrade to font-awesome 4.2. Could you please guide me how to start with? I add font-awesome 4.2 css file to my project and now its seems to be like am not able to view any fonts in my project. Any idea on what should I have to do to get 4.2 version fonts in my project.

Comment: have you updated the paths linking it in your html?

Comment: Yes I have done it @guavacat

Comment: In order to have 4.2 version, should I have replace icon-* to fa fa-* in all places I have already used in my project?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [excellent wiki](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4) put together of changes between 3.2.1 and 4.2

This includes

- a new [default syntax](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4#new-default-syntax): Changing from `icon` to `fa`
- [New icon names](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4#new-icon-names)
- other class [changes](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4#other-classes-changes)

It is most likely you are encountering that first bullet point change.

The new format is:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
```

Previous format was

```
<i class="icon-camera-retro icon-large"></i> icon-camera-retro
```

Comment: Thank you for the information @Andy . I have already used 3.2.1 version all over my project. Should I have to rename all the fonts to work for version 4.2?